# Button that responds to UIControlEventTouchUpInside and touches methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have created a button:

```
button = [StretchableButton new];
[button addTarget:mainViewController action:@selector(addNumberFromButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Inside the `StretchableButton` class I have:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; 
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
    [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event]; 
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event]; 
}
```

Touch methods are called, but `button` does not react to clicks.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to get the button to do here... Are you trying to make the button's width expand on drag? (I am guessing that because you call it stretchable button)

Comment: Sorry for my English. I have view with button. I want to move view by finger if I touch button and pull it. If I just touch button I want to call method addNumberFromButton:

Comment: Ah ok. the super thing listed below by sch should work. Best of luck.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work... :(

Comment: To keep things clear, try updating your question by explaining what you are trying to achieve and by adding more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add gesture recognizer, code sample:

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesturePan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
    gesturePan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    gesturePan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    gesturePan.delegate = self;
    [myButton addGestureRecognizer:gesturePan];
    [gesturePan release];
```

....

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {


    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:[gesture.view superView]];
//add calculation view location on it superview
    [gesture.view superView] setCenter:newLocation];

}
```